# Selenium xpath issue for document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write below snippet in selenium driver xpath but its not working. its giving Too many characters in character literal error message.

Below is the html mark up, I need to click on the button, below xpath is working for the first time and when i run the same code for second time below code is  not workng.

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'slds-button slds-button_icon-more')]");
```

[image]

below work around i am using to click the same button on second time but xpath is not correct.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open')[0].firstElementChild.onclick()


 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 jse.executeScript('document.getElementsByClassName(\'slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open\')[0].firstElementChild.onclick()');
```

can some one help me to write this snippet in xpath to get the first element child

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open')]
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: That is incorrect xpath. Change the xpath to : `By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open']")`

Comment: @KunduK how to get the first element child by using xpath

Comment: you need to provide relevant HTML and mentioned what you want to do, without that can't say anything.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open')[0].firstElementChild.onclick()
This needs to be convert into xpath

Comment: Sorry without HTML can't say anything?

Comment: Thanks, is there any tool or plugin available to get the xpath ??

Comment: use XPath Generator(link-https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-generator/dphfifdfpfabhbkghlmnkkdghbmocfeb ) extension for generating auto xpath.